# C - Memory leak on adding elements to odd numbered indices in array of linked lists, but not even

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I have a simple linked list struct called node, an array of head nodes, a linkedListManage function, and an addNode function, however I would appreciate some help diagnosing a segfault issue that I do not understand.

I have traced the issue when adding nodes to a statement in main:

```
while(1) linkedListManage(*heads);
```

While the pointer to heads is included, I get a segfault whenever I am adding the second element (never the first) to any linked list head that is stored at the ODD INDEX (never any issues with the even index) in my array of linked list heads.  I have tested this with an array size of 20 for the head and the problem still persisted to only affect the odd indices.

However, when I remove the pointer to heads:

```
while(1) linkedListManage(heads);
```

this removes the segfault error and allows my lists to add properly, but then gives the 2 warnings:

```
main.c:42:27: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'node *[2]' to parameter of type
      'node *' (aka 'struct node_t *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  while(1) linkedListManage(heads);
                          ^~~~~
main.c:27:27: note: passing argument to parameter 'heads' here
void linkedListManage(node* heads){
```

Below is my program, I would really like to know what is causing this issue so that I can learn more about whatever pointer issue this happens to be, and so i can stop having warnings.  I am completely stumped as to why this issue would only appear on the odd indices.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_t{
  int data;
  struct node_t* next;
} node;

void addNode(node* a){
  int userInput;

  node* current = a;

  printf("Enter value: ");
  scanf("%d", &userInput);    

  if (!current->data) current->data = userInput;
  else { 
    while(current->next) current = current->next;

    node* newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->data = userInput;
    current->next = newNode;
  }
}

void linkedListManage(node* heads){
    int userInput;

    printf("Enter ID of list:\n");

    scanf("%d", &userInput);

    addNode(&heads[userInput]);
}

int main(){
  node* heads[2];
  heads[0] = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
  heads[1] = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

  while(1) linkedListManage(heads);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The warnings tell you everything you need to know.  You're effectively trying to pass node ** to a function that takes a node*.  Your `linkedListManage()` function should take a `node * heads[2]` or a `node **` to function correctly.  In addition, you should never accept user input without some kind of sanity check.  What do you think will happen if the user enters 20 instead of 1 or 2?

Comment: Oh i see, thanks! That fixed it.  Also yeah I do have input validation but I had broken my code-base down to just the error area to troubleshoot and for this post to simplify :)

Answer (score 0):

```
while(1) linkedListManage(heads);
```

should be

```
while(1) linkedListManage(heads[1]);
```

as otherwise you are passing `node **` to a function that expects `node *`.